# Better way to check if function is already bound in plain JavaScript ?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, bind

I'm in a situation where I would want to know if a function is already bound in order to set a warning message when that function is invoked with `call` or `apply` with a different context.

```
function myfn (){ }
/* or */
var myfn = function () {}


var ref = myfn.bind(null);
```

I checked the function object in Firefox and Chrome console and the only difference I found is that the bound version has the name prefixed with `bound`.

```
> myfn.name
> "myfn"

> ref.name
> "bound myfn"
```

1. Is this a reliable check ?
2. Are there more ways to find if
   function is already bound ?

*NOTE:  Not interested in older browsers (ex : `<ie10`)

Comment: "*I would want to know if a function is already bound*" - no. You should not care what functions you invoke and whether they choose to use `this` or not.

Comment: You are right, but I need it for pub-sub module I'm writing not for ordinary functions.

Comment: Even a pub-sub module uses ordinary functions, right? You cannot - and should not - force the user of your module to reference the `this` value you're calling his functions on.

Comment: @Bergi - I have one use-case for wanting to know whether a function is already bound.  Assume a utility function `bindEach` that takes an object and an array of properties the developer chooses to bind.  Something like `const log = bindEach(console, ['log', 'error'])`.  I'd like `bindEach` to throw an error if the properties were pre-bound, because otherwise the developer could see unexpected behavior.

Comment: @aaaaaa There's nothing unexpected. Notice the method could just as well be an arrow function or a function that doesn't use `this` - in which case `.bind()` won't do anything useful either.

Comment: I think a developer should expect a function that is documented to use `this` to follow proper bind semantics.  The only way to ensure it is to know whether bind was already called on said function.  FYI I ended up writing a sister function `adhere` which follows predictable semantics using closures.  To me `bind` is not worth using due its "fail silently" rebinding behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this a reliable check?

No. It only works since ES6, but it also can be fooled since ES6 because `.name`s are writable now.

> Are there more ways to find if function is already bound?

Bound functions do not have a `.prototype` property, but notice that there are others that share this quality, e.g. all arrow functions.

Comment: Do you know of any other case where this property holds true? I need to find out if a function is bindable. An arrow function can't be bound, which is a behavior shared by a function already bound to some value. So, it make sense to check `.prototype` to determine if the function is bindable, unless there are other cases where `.prototype` can be `undefined`

Comment: @AkashKurianJose ES6 method definitions don't have `.prototype`s either, and they are functions that you would want to bind. No, you do **not** "*need to find out if a function is bindable*". Let the function object deal with this itself - just call `bind` upon it and let it figure out what to do.

Comment: you're right. ES6 method definitions are something I'll have to handle very often. Thanks for pointing that out. A few hours after asking, I figured it myself that finding a method's "bind-ability" is not something I should be doing. Agree with you on that too. Thanks for the info.